# I won't be able to go in front of her again

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

A child ran away from his house, because he felt that his parents were being a bit hard on him.( He was immature). Actually his parents were trying to protect him. So, when that boy realized that he felt guilty, do he said:

> I'll never be able to **go in front of** her again.

Is the use of "go in front of" natural? He says that he can never face his mom again.

Comment: No, ***go in front of her*** is not at all natural here. You already used the natural phrasing *(**face** her)* in your own text. Why would you even *want* to find an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

To my ear "go in front of" is a bit unnatural or awkward, but not incorrect. I would use **before** instead of **in front of**:

> I'll never be able to **come before** her again.

or

> I'll never be able to **go before** her again.

The phrase **in front of her** suggests plainly the physical location whereas **before her** suggests being with her, in her presence for some purpose. Also **before** is just fewer syllables to say. =P

That being said, the phrasing you already mentioned in your question is great too:

> I'll never be able to **face** her again.

Using this phrasing also suggests more than just plain physical location, even some emotional or psychological aspects of interacting with the mother. If anybody thinks of other good verb phrases, please comment. :)

Comment: Would *appear* work, i.e., would it be more idiomatic instead of *go*, or would it perhaps suggest a different meaning? I think another related idiom is *be unable to look someone in the eye(s) / face*.